# Vue3+gridstack js responsive

Tags: vue.js, responsive-design, dashboard, echarts, gridstack

I am trying to create a responsive dashboard in vue3 using gridstack js, the problem is that when I instantiate a component inside a widget and resize the widget, the component is not resized, I mainly have echarts charts and bootstrap tables that are responsive when used on pages but are not resizing when I resize the widgets, any help is appreciated

I enclosed each custom component inside a widget where each component is responsive by itself. I also tried many codepens but they don't have a specific application i.e. using a component inside a gridstack widget like I am trying to do.

I have

```js
    chart.setOption(options); 
    window.addEventListener('resize', function () { 
        const newWidth = window.innerWidth; 
        const newHeight = window.innerHeight; 
        console.log("W:", newWidth," H: ", newHeight);
        chart.resize(newWidth, newHeight); 
    });
```

but it is not getting triggered when used inside a gridstack widget, when using it on a page it works

Comment: Did you [resize](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.resize) the chart instances?

Comment: Yes, i did. I have chart.setOption(options);
            window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
                const newWidth = window.innerWidth;
                const newHeight = window.innerHeight;
                console.log("W:", newWidth," H: ", newHeight)
                chart.resize(newWidth, newHeight);
            }) but it is not getting triggered when used inside a gridstack widget, when using it on a page it works, thanks anyways!